# C# wsdl web service method multiple parameters

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio-2012, wsdl, asmx

I've consumed a WSDL web service in Visual Studios 2012 and it's given me some methods to use. Please forgive me I'm a newbie to this. One of the methods requires 3 parameters as follows:

```
public string SendMessages(int DeviceID, string DeviceSecret,anamespace.MyService.DeviceMessage[] Messages)
    Member of anamespace.MyService.DeviceInterface
```

I cannot figure out how to insert/use the third argument DeviceMessage[] which happens to be a public class under anamespace.Myservice with several variable types in t as follows:

```
public class DeviceMessage
    Member of anamespace.Myservice.
```

with:

```
public string employeenum {set;get;}
    Member of anamespace.Myservice.DeviceMessage

public int messagenum {set;get;}
    Member of anamespace.Myservice.DeviceMessa
```

ge
ect...

I've tried doing this in my Main():

```
Myservice.DeviceInterface device_interface = new Myservice.DeviceInterface();
Myservice.DeviceMessage[] device_message = new Myservice.DeviceMessage[0];

string emp_num = device_message[0].employeenum;
emp_num = "123";
```

etc...

```
string Results;
Results = device_interface.SendMessages(987654,"SomeString",device_message[0])
```

This is where I'm stuck.

Thanks!

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I'm getting the following: The best overloaded method match for anamespace.MyService.DeviceInterface.SendMessages(int,string,anamespace.Myservice.DeviceMessage[]) has some invalid arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

> anamespace.Myservice.DeviceMessage deviceMessage = new anamespace.Myservice.DeviceMessage();
>   deviceMessage.employeenum = "123";
>   anamespace.Myservice.DeviceMessage[] device_messages = {deviceMessage};
>   string Results = device_interface.SendMessages(987654,"SomeString",device_messages);

Comment: Thanks you guys! The key line missing in my logic was: anamespace.MyService.DeviceMessage[] device_messages = {deviceMessage};

Answer (score 0):

May be in you method third argument requires array of DeviceMessage and you are passing only first element of your array that is device_message[0].

Instead of device_message[0] try to pass device_message.

Comment: Tried that and i still get the same error:                                                    The best overloaded method match for anamespace.MyService.DeviceInterface.SendMessages(int,string,anamespace.Myservic‌​e.DeviceMessage[]) has some invalid arguments